# javascript - how to use a text box input in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to write a solution for a javascript application that takes a number input & depending on that number is how many times it runs a specific function. I am using a text box for input field & a button to process the number of times the user wants the function to run. It is for a game of dice game. User enters how many games he wants to play and clicks button to run the roll_dice function that many times. I'm not sure if I am going the right way with using a for loop to take users numeric input and loop through its value until it ends for example

```
function games() {
        var num = document.getElementById("inp").vale;
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            roll_dice();
        }
}
```

Comment: what is vale?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. It's `.value`.

You can convert a string to a number by using `* 1`.

Something like this:

```js
function games() {

  var num = document.getElementById("inp").value * 1; // Convert the string value a number.
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    roll_dice();
  }
}

function roll_dice() {
  console.log("Test.");
}

var btnRun = document.getElementById("btnRun");
btnRun.onclick = function() {
  games();
};
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text" />
<button id="btnRun" type="button">Run</button>
```

Comment: I appreciate everyone's helps. Danny, I understood your example best, thank you! Now i am stuck with my roll_dice function. I am missing something to allow it to process and display each roll_dice output. This is what I have

Comment: function roll_dice() {

    var die1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
    var die2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;

    var sum =  die1 + die2;

    var output = "<br>Your Roll = " + sum;
 
 var total = sum;

    if ((sum==7)||(sum==11))  output = output + "<br>You win!";
    else output = output + "<br>You Loose!";
    
    document.getElementById("op").innerHTML = output;
  }

Comment: Oh, could you update your post with this code? I can help you.

Comment: Danny, I apologize for the delayed response. I was able to figure it out, I had to put my win variable outside the function and into a global variable. I appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

The value you get from input box is string you need to convert it into int . If you are using int in loop .

```
var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("inp").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function games() {

    var num = document.getElementById("inp").value;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < Number(num); i++) {
        roll_dice();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**<label>Game:</label><input type="text" id="input" value="0" />
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
  <script>
 document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var inputVal=document.getElementById("input").value*1;
  rollDice(inputVal);
});

 function rollDice(dice){
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>Game:</label><input type="text" id="input" value="0" />
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
  <script>
 document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var inputVal=document.getElementById("input").value*1;
  rollDice(inputVal);

});
    
 function rollDice(dice){
  for(var i =0;i<dice;i++){
    var x = Math.random()*100;
    console.log(x);} 
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
  for(var i =0;i<dice;i++){
    var x = Math.random()*100;
    console.log(x);} 
}
 </script>**
```